# Trouble with mySql function

Tags: mysql

I have to create a function in mysql that returns an integer. The sql interpreter keeps telling me that I have a problem with my syntax. I looked it over the best I could and tried a bunch of things, but I just can't figure it out.

```
CREATE FUNCTION no_of_paintings_exhibited (exhibition_name VARCHAR(45))
RETURNS INT

BEGIN
    DECLARE number_of_paintings INT;

    SELECT
    COUNT(*)
    INTO number_of_paintings
    FROM Exhibition, Shown_at, Painting
    WHERE name = exhibition_name AND Painting.id_no = Shown_at.art;

    RETURN number_of_paintings;

END; //
```

Error output:

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION no_of_paintings_exhibited (exhibition_name VARCHAR(45))
-> RETURNS INT
-> 
-> BEGIN
->         DECLARE number_of_paintings INT;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: Pleaes try this  `DECLARE number_of_paintings INT;    set  number_of_paintings=0;   `

Comment: I have tried adding a default value and using a set expression. No dice :(

Comment: Can you check the `FROM Exhibition, Shown_at, Painting` statement.

Comment: In what way? If I run the 'Select' statement on its own, removing only the 'INTO' statement, the query is properly intepreted and returns the correct result

Comment: is it `into` or `As`  ie.  `select count(*)  as number_of_Paintings`   I m not sure of this   . SELECT INTO command creates new table and can be copied data from one database to another

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION no_of_paintings_exhibited (exhibition_name VARCHAR(45))
RETURNS INT

BEGIN
    DECLARE number_of_paintings INT;
set number_of_paintings=0;
    SELECT
    COUNT(*)
    as number_of_paintings
    FROM Exhibition ex, Shown_at shat, Painting ptng
    WHERE ex.name = exhibition_name AND ptng.id_no = shat.art;

    RETURN number_of_paintings;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not set the DELIMITER, by default semi-colon (;) is the delimiter and as soon as it finds the first semi-colon it tries to execute and throw this error

Do as follows (set the delimiter to $$ or // before creating the function, below I used $$ ) and then again after function is created again set the DELIMITER to semi-colon.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION ...
..
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```